# How to merge/combine date (year) under certain circumstances

Tags: excel, combinations

This is my first post in the forum so i ask for your grace.
I have the following table

Example Before
[image]

What i want to achieve is: if i have the same sku, brand and cc in a couple of lines, then to combine the valid from year and valid until year.
For example: lines 2,3,4,5 should be combined to one line like

Example after
[image]

Is there any chance to achieve it as the file i am working on a file of 30000 lines!
Thank you in advance,

Regards,

John

Comment: But there isn't row for first SKU validity from 2003 to 2004?  Are only min & max to be considered and missing years not to be taken into account?

Comment: You are partly right. Yes there might be a problem when a year is missed but not on the line you mention. The problem may exist in the following scenario:

P40230058 KAWASAKI 100 KX 1998 2000
P40230058 KAWASAKI 100 KX 2001 2004
P40230058 KAWASAKI 100 KX 2005 2009
P40230058 KAWASAKI 100 KX 2011 2012
P40230058 KAWASAKI 100 KX 2013 2013
P40230058 KAWASAKI 100 KX 2014 2014

If you see year 2010 is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `Excel365` then try below formula.

```
G2=UNIQUE(A2:C14)
J2=MINIFS($D$2:$D$14,$A$2:$A$14,G2,$B$2:$B$14,H2,$C$2:$C$14,I2)
K2=MAXIFS($D$2:$D$14,$A$2:$A$14,G2,$B$2:$B$14,H2,$C$2:$C$14,I2)
```

[image]